# Running a flask instance in python in the background

Tags: python, flask

I have a class and I am running this currently

```
class Bartender:
   def run(self):    
       while self._running:
            time.sleep(0.1)

bartender = Bartender()
bartender.run()
```

Now I want to add a simple webgui how do i do this so that the webserver is running in background and I don't need to change the main function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use celery instead of your function -> https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/celery/

```
from celery import Celery
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask 
import threading
 
class Bartender:    
     def run(self):    
        while self._running:
             time.sleep(0.1)
 
bartender = Bartender()
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/') 
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

start the app in a separate thread

```
thread = Thread(target = app.run)  
thread.start()
```

And start the bartender

```
bartender.run()
```

...
Finally join the thread

```
thread.join()
```

Comment: Why do we run the flask app in the new thread ? We could run the bartender object in the new thread right ?

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: I testes it as @André Soblechero told but the class is not reactiing on button inputs

Comment: You can also run the bartender object in a seperate thread.